# Question About Multiple Sorting in Word Press

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting

I have a page that shows standings for an online Fifa league, the standings should be sorted by Points and then Goal Differential. I collect the data for Wins, Draws, Losses, Goals For and Goals against. Here is my code -

```
            <?php
                $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'post', 
                'cat' => '5',
                'numberposts' => 12,
                'meta_query'    => array( 
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    '_fifa_w' => array(
                        'key'       => '_fifa_w',
                    ),
                    '_fifa_d' => array(
                        'key'       => '_fifa_d',
                    ),
                    '_fifa_gf' => array(
                        'key'       => '_fifa_gf',
                    ),
                    '_fifa_ga' => array(
                        'key'       => '_fifa_ga',
                    ),
                ),
            'orderby' => array(
                '_fifa_w'       => 'DESC',
                '_fifa_d'     => 'DESC',
                '_fifa_gf'     => 'ASC',
                '_fifa_ga'     => 'DESC'
                )
            );
                $product_posts = get_posts( $args );
            ?>
```

This sorts by total points but does nothing for the goal differential. If I exclude _fifa_w (wins) and _fifa_d (draws) from the code like this -

```
          'orderby' => array(
                '_fifa_gf'     => 'ASC',
                '_fifa_ga'     => 'DESC'
                )
            );
```

Then it sorts by goal differential properly.

How can I get it to all work togetheR?

Comment: Good catch that was just a typo. I edited my post, should be _fifa_ga instead

Comment: I don't WP, so I'll ask you to try something before I post an answer...  `'orderby' => '_fifa_w _fifa_d _fifa_gf-_fifa_ga', 'order' => 'DESC'`  I don't know if WP will try to quote the subtraction as a single column.

Comment: That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
'orderby' => '_fifa_w _fifa_d _fifa_gf-_fifa_ga',
'order' => 'DESC'
```

I don't use Wordpress, but the idea is to sort by the first two columns normally, then sort on the calculated difference between the goalsfor and goals against.

Probably a good idea not to blindly trust me, but to eyeball the rendered query to be sure that Wordpress isn't backtick-wrapping the mathematical expression.  Maybe `$wp_query->request` will show you what is being rendered.

Otherwise, there is always the php option of `usort()` on your result set.